# Creating linear model with R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a simple linear regression using a custom dataset based on following code :

```
data(iris)
head(iris)

fit1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = iris)
summary(fit1)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red")
```

Which generates :

[image]

To modify this  code for custom dataset where y axis values are 100,200,300 and x axis values are 1,2,3 I use :

```
> rg <- data.frame("y"=integer() , "x" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(100 , 1)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(200 , 2)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(300 , 3)
> fit1 <- lm(rg.x ~ rg.y, data = rg)
```

But I receive error :

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'rg.x' not found
```

But `rg.x` does exist :

```
rg
    y x
1 100 1
2 200 2
3 300 3
```

Have I not setup the dataframe correctly ?

Update :

Solution thanks to @PinkFluffyUnicorn

```
> rg <- data.frame("y"=integer() , "x" = integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(100 , 1)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(200 , 2)
> rg[nrow(rg) + 1, ] <- c(300 , 3)
> fit1 <-lm(x~y,data=rg)
> 
> ggplot(rg, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
+     geom_point() +
+     stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're mixing python and R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`fit1 <-lm(x~y,data=rg)`

You can't access columns of a frame with a `.`

If you would like to get the values of one column, you should use the $ sign, e.g. `rg$x`

Comment: it certainly did, I've updated question with complete solution for reference.